# unable to post item to database, Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I have a model called CurrentBestSellersListItem, with an integer field, some CharFields, and a URLField. I also have a serializer for the given model. I am able to create instances of the CurrentBestSellersListItem in the database manually from http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/lists/currentbestsellerslistitem/add/, i.e. from the admin panel, but am unable to create them on another route. The other route I have (in urls.py) is:

```
path('list-items-create/', views.create_saved_list_item, name='create_saved_list_item'),
```

and the create_saved_list_item function in views.py is:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_saved_list_item(request): 
  json_object = json.dumps(request.data, indent = 1) 
  serializer = CurrentBestSellersListItemSerializer(data=json_object)
  if serializer.is_valid(): 
    serializer.save()
  return Response(serializer.data)
```

If I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/list-items-create/ and POST the following data:

```
{
"rank": 555, 
"weeks_on_list": 555, 
"publisher": "a", 
"description": "b", 
"title": "c", 
"author": "d",
"amazon_product_url": "amazon.com/books/5"
}
```

then I get back this response:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: OPTIONS, POST
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{}
```

and the item is NOT added to the connected database, as expected. Can any of you spot where the error is?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with you code.

First of all, you should not use `json.dumps()`, as the serializer does not take a string but a dict to create your model.
Dependening on how your request is structured, you could directly pass the request body or the request JSON to the serializer.

```py
json_object = json.parse(request.data) 
serializer = CurrentBestSellersListItemSerializer(data=json_object)
```

The second thing is, you are not returning any message or info in case the data is not valid.

```py
if serializer.is_valid(): 
    serializer.save()
```

Just add some error logging there to find out whats wrong with the data you are sending.

```py
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
else:
    return JSONResponse({'errors': serializer.errors, 'input_data': json_object, 'validated_data': serializer.validated_data})
```

If you do not like to return a `JSONResponse` with error details, you could just add `raise_exception=True` to your validation.

```py
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True): 
    serializer.save()
```